# Odd offset in QT Window when using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to have three different windows showing different orthogonal views into a 3D data set.
I've got a toolbar as my mainwindow, and this just toggles the visibility of the other windows.

My view windows are in a class called SliceView. It displays an image to show what view it is, and also has a yellow line I've added for trying to figutre out why I have an offset from the corner of the window.

```
#include "sliceview.h"
#include "ui_sliceview.h"

SliceView::SliceView(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::SliceView)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   viewArea = new QGraphicsView;
   scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, this->x(), this->y(), this);
   viewArea->setScene(scene);
   setCentralWidget(viewArea);

}

void SliceView::ShowSlice(size_t slice)
{
   
   //slice not used in minimal example
   
   scene->clear();
   if (m_plane == XYPLANE)
   {
       setWindowTitle("XY");
       image = QPixmap(":/images/XY.png");
   }
   else if (m_plane == YZPLANE)
   {
       setWindowTitle("YZ");
       image = QPixmap(":/images/YZ.png");
   }
   else
   {
       setWindowTitle("XZ");
       image = QPixmap(":/images/XZ.png");
   }
   scene->addPixmap(image);
   scene->addLine(0,0,100,100,QPen(Qt::yellow));

   scene->update();
   auto width = image.width();
   auto height = image.height();
   viewArea->resize(width,height);
   viewArea->resize(scene->width(),scene->height());
   viewArea->update();
}
```

This produces a window like this, where the image is offset from the corner top left corner of the window. I want the window to resize to the image it contains, and for the 0,0 co-ordinate of the image + window to be the top  left corner.
Where am I going wrong?

[The full (minimum) project can be found here](https://github.com/g7uvw/QT_MDI_Test/tree/Reorder-all-The-Things)

[image: Image showing the issue, the gradient image isn't where I want it in the window]

Comment: try add `viewArea->setAligment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);`

Comment: That needs a QLayout, I was hoping to avoid that if I just needed one image and perhaps a few lines drawn on a canvas. I just find it odd that adding a scene to a window doesn't keep the same origins.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you give parameters to the constructor incorrectly

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, this->x(), this->y(), this);
```

`this->x()` and `this->y()`  will always return `0` I suggest using  [setSceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop)

```
 scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
 scene->setSceneRect(-1.5, -1.5, 1.5, 1.5); 
 ui->viewArea->setScene(scene);
 ui->viewArea->show();
```

the rest can be done like this

```
 ...
 QRectF bound = scene->itemsBoundingRect();
 bound.setWidth(image.width());         
 bound.setHeight(image.height());
 ui->viewArea->fitInView(bound, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
 ui->viewArea->centerOn(0, 0);
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry it took me a while to reply. I've made the edits you suggest, but still get the same offset. I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work. I thought adding an image t a window would be the easy bit of this project!